# How would one make a custom gui in C#

Tags: c#, user-interface

I am interested in making a custom gui in C#, and I would like some advice as how to best go about that. The attached picture is generally what I would like to create - namely drawing text, boxes/backgrounds, pictures, lines, circles, and other gui elements (Like text input fields and the like).

I don't really know where to start, what I have been able to gleam from google searches is that GDI+ and using the paint event might be able to do what I am looking for - but I don't know if that is the way to go about making such a thing, or if it is the wrong tool for the job (aka it is slow/ineffective compared to something else).

```
//something along the lines of this: 
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Graphics graphicsObj;

    graphicsObj = this.CreateGraphics();

    Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 5);

    Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(20, 20, 250, 200);

    graphicsObj.DrawRectangle(myPen, myRectangle);
}
```

Thank you for your time, and forgive me if I said anything incorrectly; I am having a hard time even describing to google what I am looking to do--- so your help is really appreciated!!!!

[image: A cool looking node based GUI thing from 3ds max]

Comment: As someone who has been working alot with WPF, this would be possible for me to make using WPF. However I doubt it is the best solution. I have also worked with game-engines, but they use mostly C++ and their own GUI libraries. Really interested in hearing some other answers..

Comment: You definitely don't want to use the Paint event for everything. A GUI is made up of controls, controls and more controls. Shop around for some WinForms or WPF frameworks.

Comment: It's a rather broad question as it depends entirely on the application and how GUI elements have to interact with the program logic behind it.  The MVVM of WPF is meant so that GUI designer can be independent of the business logic programmer behind it. That of course creates some overhead and latencies, however it is a rather good approach for a general purpose GUI / program interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) an option for you? I would recommend it based on the screenshot you provided. This desktop GUI technology is much better suited than WinForms as your code sample suggests you are using.

- Learn the basic of WPF and XAML via the link I provided.
- Then learn about the [Canvas](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/canvas/) panel
- Then I suggest you learn about [Templates](http://www.wpftutorial.net/templates.html)

Well, this should get you going. If you have any specific questions I'm sure we' ll be happy to help here at SO.

**Update** Example of Canvas panel in Items control: https://dannyvanderkraan.wordpress.com/2015/02/12/wpf-listbox-with-arbitrary-positioning-and-custom-shaped-items/

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. To be honest, I don't know much at all about WPF (other than it has a bunch of html looking stuff in it), and I will look into that.

In what way(s) is WPF much better suited than WinForms?

Thank you so very much again for your help!

Comment: Well next to performance reasons (it renders graphics differently than WinForms) it is also much better suited for developing rich GUIs due to the very core it leans on... XAML. With WinForms you often have to hack together your own WinControl or buy very expensive ones to get what you need. With WPF you can for instance in your example put a Canvas panel as ItemTemplate in a ItemsControl and have it render each item according to an ItemTemplate which you assemble from various controls to look like the ones in your screenshot. All natively supported. Nice and smooth developer experience.

Comment: Can't get much better than that, thanks so much again for your help!

Comment: You are welcome to check out an old blog post of mine (see update answer). It described the steps of what I said earlier. It's a bit advanced though, you might want to check it when you know a bit more about WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You may use WPF or you can search for Windows Forms themes. You can do amazing custom gui by customising windows forms. If you are to create a new project I would suggest you WPF because it is easier to implement custom guy (especially transparency)